# sequelize create a column with generated values

Tags: node.js, model, sequelize.js

I am creating table using sequelize model.

```
Gsdatatab.init({
    SCRIP: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
    },
    LTP: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    OHL: DataTypes.STRING,
    ALERT: DataTypes.FLOAT,
    PROFIT: DataTypes.FLOAT
 }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Gsdatatab',
    timestamps: true,
  });
  return Gsdatatab;
};
```

Now I have a small requirement where I want to auto populate the PROFIT column as LTP - ALERT or ALERT - LTP based on value of OHL(B or S).In mysql currently I manually altered the column with sql script as below

```
`PROFIT` float GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((`ALERT` - `LTP`)) VIRTUAL`
```